# How can I mirror the x and y axis?

Tags: core-plot

I would like to make a plot where the second x and y axis are simply a mirror of the primary axis. For example like this typical scientific style plot with the inner facing tick marks, 
[image: and mirrored x and y axis].

It this easy to accomplish with coreplot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create two new axes, one for x and one for y. Configure them to match the other axes, except change the `tickDirection` to point the other way and position them at the opposite side of the graph (using the `orthogonalCoordinateDecimal` or constraints). Assign both new axes to the same plot space used by the other axes. Add all four axes to an array and pass it to the axis set:

```
graph.axisSet.axes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:x, y, x2, y2, nil];
```

There is an example of adding additional axes to a graph in the [Plot Gallery demo app](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/source/browse/examples/CorePlotGallery/src/plots/AxisDemo.m#80).

Comment: Thank you Eric, that helps a lot I've got it to work. One further point: when the axis uses CPTAxisLabelingPolicyNone not tick marks are drawn, and when CPTAxisLabelingPolicyAutomatic is used tick marks and axis labels are drawn. It is possible to only draw the tick and not the labels?

Comment: Sure, set the `labelFormatter` to nil.

Comment: Ha, that's better than what I came up with! I set the axis text to transparent :) Thanks again.